# Associative, but non-commutative binary operation with a identity and inverse

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can there really be an associative, but non-commutative binary operation with a identity and inverse?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! to make your question more useful to the community, it might be helpful why you seem to doubt that this is possible.

Comment: Such a structure is called a (non-commutative) group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Yes***, and there are plenty of them:

- For any set $X$, you can define a binary operation $\circ$ on the set of mappings $f:X\to X$ as $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ (composition). This operation, in general is not commutative, but it is associative and has an inverse.
- On the set of all invertible matrices of size $n\times n$, the standard binary operation of multiplying matrices is not commutative. It has an inverse, and is associative.
- For any $n$, the set of all permutations of $n$ elements has a non-commutative (if $n>2$) associative operation with an inverse.

In fact, most *groups* studied in group theory are non-abelian (meaning their operation is not commutative). For any $n$, the number of finite groups of size at most $n$ is **much** larger than the number of finite Abelian groups of size at most $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, matrix multiplication: given two square matrices $A,B$ with non-zero determinant (so elements of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$) of any size, we know that $AB$ does not have to be equal to $BA$, but $A(BC) = (AB)C$, the identity matrix serves as an identity and $A^{-1}$ is defined uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) are an extension of real and complex numbers that is a [skew field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_ring). This means that there are two operations (a sum and a product) that have the same properties as the usual operations on real (or complex) numbers and also division (by non zero elements) is always possible, but the product is not commutative.